# select value from dropdown after bind the options in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a model in an angular module

```
$scope.employee  = {}
$scope.countries={}
$scope..employee.Country_id = 10
$scope.employee.City_id = 50
```

then I'm binding two select elements in the following manner

```
$http.get("/api/initdataapi/GetCountry").success(function (data) {
    $scope.countries = data;
});
$scope.$watch('employee.Country_id', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    var url = "/api/initdataapi/GetByCountry/" + newValue;
    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
        $scope.Cities = data;

    });
```

the problem is when the page has loaded the angular binds the country and select the value of `employee.Country_id` and for that the `$watch` detect model changes and fires the `getCities`, the angular binds the cities into the select element but it's not selecting the employee city

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 premove">
    <span>Nationality</span>
    <select ng-model="employee.Country_id " >
        <option ng-repeat="county in countries" value="{{county.Id}}">{{county.Name_En}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 premove">
    <span>Place of birth -{{employee.City_Id}}</span>
    <select ng-model="employee.City_Id">
        <option ng-repeat="birthCity in Cities" value="{{birthCity.City_Id}}">{{birthCity.City_Ename}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

What should I do to fix this ?

Comment: Try to alter your model to have employee and his city in a particular array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ng-option instead of select and option.
Your html should be

```
<div class="col-sm-3 premove">
                    <span>Nationality</span>
          <select ng-options="country.Id as country.Name_En for country in countries" ng-model="employee.Country_id"></select>      
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 premove">
                    <span>Place of birth -{{employee.City_Id}}</span>
         <select ng-options="birthCity.City_Id as birthCity.City_Ename for birthCity in Cities" ng-model="employee.City_Id"></select>    
                </div>
```